# ionic 4: changing ion-content background does not work

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

i have tried in global.scss as

```
ion-content{
    background-image: url('assets/images/cover.jpg');
    -webkit-background-image: url('assets/images/cover.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
  }
```

but this does not render the image. tried path as ./assets/images/cover.jpg as well.

if i put the same image as img tag on the page that shows up ruling out invalid image possibility.

I also tried to put in the homeage.scss as

```
.myview {
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/cover.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and using class="myview" in home.html no luck

Comment: @PeterHaddad link broken

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the CSS-Variable --background to change the background of ion-content.

Example:

```
ion-content{
    --background: #fff url('../../assets/images/cover.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

Put this into your components, pages or global scss.

For reference see: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#css-custom-properties

Comment: That solved my problem. But is there any solution when keyboard is pressed background image scrolls up?

Comment: @rchau Did you find a solution for when the background image scrolls up when keyboard is pressed?

Comment: @Vivek No. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @rchau not yet. I'll let you know if I find one

Comment: @vivek please find my answer below

Comment: It's flickering, anyone know how to fix this flickering annoying bug?

Answer (score 32):

I solved the problem doing the following:

```
ion-content {
    --background: none;
    background-image: url('/assets/imgs/page_bg.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will disabled background and then set the correct one.

Comment: Cheers bud this fixed it for me too :)

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to do the same in a class, and then put `<ion-content class="background-class">`

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered the similar situation, having ionic background css property leads to flickering issues on IOS

try the following if you have encountered flickering issue

```
:host {
  ion-content {
    --background:none;
    background:url(''../../assets/images/cover.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

for anyone having keyboard issues (background resizes on keyboard show) install Keyboard plugin

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

and add the following code on your config.json

```
<preference name="keyboardResize" value="false" />
<preference name="keyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
```

**Note:** this may hide item beneath the keyboard when its shown (I have tested only on iOS)

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried answer from @rchau, but it did not work in my case. Instead, I put this code in my project and it has done the right thing:

```
ion-content{
    --background:url('../../assets/images/cover.jpg') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It is advisable to add a short explanation of your code as well.

Comment: In what manner this answer is different than that of @rchau ?

Comment: @Heikki I used the top answer, but it did not work, so I put this code in my project and it has done the right thing, so I posted it to help others

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava ohk sure

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution for me.

*global.scss*

```
ion-content {
    --background: url('../assets/img/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```