# Set background image for Application - Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want o set background image for Ionic 4 Application (all page). This was pretty straight forward when using Ionic 3 but the same approach didn't worked here. I read the [theming](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics) of Ionic 4 but I couldn't find a way to set an image as background.

As given in the document, background colour can be set and it worked.

```
:root {
    --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(197deg, rgba(100,100,100,1) 0%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 13.5%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 33.33%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
}
```

But on setting the image as background, it didn't responds,

```
:root {
    --background: url('assets/imgs/appBg.png') no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

Like to know what is the possible way to set image background in Ionic 4. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 4: changing ion-content background does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399998/ionic-4-changing-ion-content-background-does-not-work)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set a background of the App, the path app the image needs to be given as in the hosted environment.

```
ion-content{
    --background: url(http://10.100.176.52:8100/appBg.png) !important;
    --background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

This will set the image as background for the complete Application.

Answer (score 1):

Set background image ionic 4:

```
ion-content {
  --background: url(../../assets/bg.jpg) no-repeat center/cover fixed;
}
```

[Ref. Url](https://chrisgriffith.wordpress.com/2019/03/02/background-images-for-ionic-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ion-content` instead `:root`.

As:

```
ion-content{
  --background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXoO.png)!important;
  --background-repeat: no-repeat;
  --background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-yl21xr?file=src/global.scss)

Comment: Thanks. This works when used as it is. I tried to replace the image src with local image. It didn't work also it did not gave any error. <                                                . .ion-content{
  --background: url(../../assets/imgs/appBg.png)!important;
  --background-repeat: no-repeat;
  --background-size:100% 100%;
} >

Comment: use `url(assets/imgs/appBg.png)`

Comment: url(assets/imgs/appBg.png) gave compile error. And using url(../../assets/imgs/appBg.png) compiled successfully and I can see the style active in ion-content on inspecting. But it is not reflecting in screen.